# Chrome starts, works for a third of a minute then crashes

Tags: google-chrome, crash, disk-utility

I got a problem with Google Chrome. This is exactly what happens:

After clicking on the chrome shortcut (which has no commands set other than running chrome), it opens after 5 seconds, then uses 100% of my disk, then crashes. I tried some of the fixes I read online, but neither worked for me. I have listed them below together with the effects they have on chrome.

**Running chrome using `--no-sandbox`**:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --no-sandbox
```

The 5-second delay at the start vanishes. Chrome starts immediately. A message appears saying that the `--no-sandbox` command is invalid. Disk usage by chrome rises to 100%. After 20 seconds, chrome crashes.

**Running chrome using `-incognito`**:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -incognito
```

Again, there is no delay at the start. The application runs in incognito mode. Disk usage also rises to 100% and then chrome crashes after the same 20 seconds.

**Disabling the antivirus (Kaspersky Internet Security):**

This doesn't work. I even uninstalled the antivirus and restarted my PC, but this changed nothing.

I am using Windows 10 Build 1709 and the latest version of chrome.

What else should I try? Is there an official fix?

Comment: Is it one particular Chrome process that uses 100% CPU? Since add-ons and tabs each run their own process, you may be able to narrow things down that way. You can use Chrome's Task Manager to get the CPU usage and process ID for each process by using `Shift + Esc`.

Comment: Delete the Chrome user profile you are currently using.  Does the behavior exhibit itself if you do that?  The message that indicates that `--no-sandbox` is an invalid command, it is generated by Windows or Chrome because I see an error in your shortcut path.  **Edit** your question, **do not submit a comment**, and provide this vital information required to answer your question.

Comment: Is it possible to delete the user profile **without** opening chrome? I can't delete it from chrome because it will crash when I open it.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try a reinstall if you haven't already. Your data and settings will be resynced when you login to Chrome, but if you aren't logged in, your user profile can be found at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\ .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try a reinstall but that didn't work.